# Keras Accuracy and Loss not changing over a large period of epochs

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to create a Convolutional Neural Network to classify what language a certain "word" is from. There are two files ("english_words.txt" and "spanish_words.txt") which each contain about 60,000 words each. I have converted each word into a 29-dimensional vector where each element is a number between 0 and 1. I am training the model for 500 epochs with the optimizer "adam". However, when I train the model, the loss tends to hover around 0.7 and the accuracy around 0.5, and no matter how long I train it for, these metrics will not improve. Here is the code:

```
import keras
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
import re

train_labels = []
train_data = []

with open("english_words.txt") as words:
    full_words = words.read()
    full_words = full_words.split("\n")

    # all of the labels are just 1.

    # we now need to encode them into 29 dimensional vectors. 
    vector = []
    i = 0
    for word in full_words:
        train_labels.append([1,0])
        for letter in word:
            vector.append((ord(letter) - 96) * (1.0 / 26.0))
            i += 1
        if (i < 29):
            for x in range(0, 29 - i):
                vector.append(0)
        train_data.append(vector)
        vector = []
        i = 0
with open("spanish_words.txt") as words:
    full_words = words.read()
    full_words = full_words.replace(' ', '')

    full_words = full_words.replace('\n', ',')
    full_words = full_words.split(",")
    vector = []
    for word in full_words:
        train_labels.append([0,1])
        for letter in word:
            vector.append((ord(letter) - 96) * (1.0 / 26.0))
            i += 1
        if (i < 29):
            for x in range(0, 29 - i):
                vector.append(0)
        train_data.append(vector)
        vector = []
        i = 0


def shuffle_in_unison(a, b):
    assert len(a) == len(b)
    shuffled_a = np.empty(a.shape, dtype=a.dtype)
    shuffled_b = np.empty(b.shape, dtype=b.dtype)
    permutation = np.random.permutation(len(a))
    for old_index, new_index in enumerate(permutation):
        shuffled_a[new_index] = a[old_index]
        shuffled_b[new_index] = b[old_index]
    return shuffled_a, shuffled_b



train_data = np.asarray(train_data, dtype=np.float32)
train_labels = np.asarray(train_labels, dtype=np.float32)



train_data, train_labels = shuffle_in_unison(train_data, train_labels)

print(train_data.shape, train_labels.shape)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(29, input_shape=(29,)))
model.add(Dense(60))
model.add(Dense(40))
model.add(Dense(25))
model.add(Dense(2))

model.compile(optimizer="adam",
              loss="categorical_crossentropy",
              metrics=["accuracy"])
model.summary()

model.fit(train_data, train_labels, epochs=500, batch_size=128)

model.save("language_predictor.model")
```

For some extra info, I am running python 3.x with tensorflow 1.15 and keras 1.15 on windows x64.

Comment: May I enquire why you are using CNN to do solve your problem? My understanding is that you do not even need a model for your job. A simple program to compare whether the given word is in which dataset is enough to tell to which language the word belongs. So what are you trying to accomplish fiddling around with a CNN?

Comment: oh it was just a little fun project for myself - fiddling and tinkering around with it as you may say :)

Comment: @neelg: And what happens if you encounter a word that is in neither of the datasets?

Comment: It is not meant to be for commercial use, and so it does not matter wether this happens or not - it is purely a test on wether this is possible or not, and is not to actually be used for anything so there is no answer to that question I am afraid. Hope this is what you were looking for, best wishes - SciencePi

Answer (score 2):

I can see several potential problems with your code.

1. You added several `Dense` layers one after another, but you really need to also include a non-linear activation function with the parameter `activation= ...`. In the absence of any non-linear activation functions, all those fully-connected `Dense` layers will mathematically collapse into one single linear `Dense` layer incapable of learning a non-linear decision boundary.
2. In general, if you see your loss and accuracy not making any improvement or even getting worse, then the first thing to try is to reduce your learning rate.
3. You don't need to necessarily implement your own shuffling function. The Keras `fit()` function can do it if you use the `shuffle=True` parameter.

Comment: hi all, just a quick update - after doing all of these fixes the model still does not train (i changed activation on the dense layers and i tried soft max and relu.) Has anybody got any other ideas because there is definitely no problem with the dataset either. thank you for the answers ;)

Comment: @sciencepi: What's the output of `train_data.shape` and `train_labels.shape`?

Comment: the shape of the two labels are as follows: `(142764, 29) ` and `(142764, 2)`

Comment: A few more remarks: (1) You stated that you wanted to create a Convolutional Neural Network (presumably over characters), but your architecture is a standard densely-connected neural network (that is, there are no convolutional layers. (2) Are you certain that your 29-D encoders are implemented correctly? (3) When you say `the loss tends to hover around 0.7 and the accuracy around 0.5`, do you mean the loss and accuracy start at that level or increase towards that level?

Comment: I mean they start at that level and do not change - this is stated in the original question :)

Comment: also, the vectors are constructed by creating numbers from zero to one that correspond to letters (e.g. ‘A’ is 0.12907). I have checked that this is completing correctly and I can assure you that there is no issue with this process. - SciencePi

Comment: If you simplify your network to, say, 2 layers, then do your results get worse? If you add more layers or hidden units, then do your results get better? If  you can't observe these patterns, then there is something wrong with your code.

Comment: when I remove layers, the network’s accuracy does increase for 2-3 epochs and then the loss spikes from 3.0 to 8.0. This makes accuracy decrease from 0,60 to 0,40. When there are more layers, this just happens slower. Hope this is the answer you are looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the points mentioned by stackoverflowuser2010:

1. I find this a very good read and highly suggest checking the mentioned points: [37 Reasons why your Neural Network is not working](https://blog.slavv.com/37-reasons-why-your-neural-network-is-not-working-4020854bd607)
2. Center your input data: Compute a component-wise mean vector and subtract it from every input.